# List partial duplicate filenames to a text file - DOS/BATCH

Tags: duplicates, filenames

I have thousand of files listed by serial numbers and date/time produced by testing and all are in the same directory. Some are tested twice. I would like to find those duplicate serial numbers and list them in a text file. The first 12 characters will be the same for a number tested twice.

```
ALT_1049670_20130302-103355_Results.log
ALT_1049669_20130302-103022_Results.log --\
ALT_1049669_20130302-102811_Results.log ---- tested twice
```

I've started with this code:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
set dupl=%%~na
set dupl=!dupl:~0,12!
echo !dupl! >> dupl.txt
)
```

But it lists all of the files (at least the first 12 characters). I'm not sure how to get it to compare and only list the duplicates.

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
set dupl=%%~na
set dupl=%%a
set dupl=!dupl:~4,7!
echo !dupl! >> dupl.txt
)
call C:\PHP\PHP.exe dupl.php
notepad duplicate.txt
```

The call to dupl.php

```
<?php
$file = file('dupl.txt');
$a = array();

foreach($file as $f)
{
++$a[strtolower(trim($f))];
}
foreach($a as $key => $value)
{
if($value > 1)
{
$f = fopen("duplicate.txt", "a");
echo $key . PHP_EOL;
fwrite($f, $key . "\r\n");  
}
}
fclose($f);
```